# How to scrape historical data using selenium with drop downs?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape historical and predicted hourly prices of energy from the following URL: https://hourlypricing.comed.com/pricing-table-today/

I was able to do so for the other table here which is tomorrows predicted prices https://hourlypricing.comed.com/pricing-table-tomorrow/

...dealing with the drop-down is a bit over my head thus far.

I don't fully understand how this could be done with a date picker. What I would like to do is to pull the data for all of 2018. 
When I use the Selenium IDE to record what steps to take it does 
not increment the year at all when in record mode but works fine when I change the date with out recording? Any pointers as to how to approach this problem would be appreciated. From what I understand so far is that I should be able to record the commands in the IDE and than write the same code in python?

```py
from pandas.io.html import read_html
from selenium import webdriver
from operator import itemgetter
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://hourlypricing.comed.com/pricing-table-tomorrow/')

table = driver.find_element_by_class_name('prices')
tablehtml = table.get_attribute('outerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(tablehtml,'xml')
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "prices" })
#print(table)
table_body = table.find('tbody')
#print(table_body)

data = []
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    cents = cols[1]
    cents = cents[:-1]
    cols[1] = cents
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

sortedData = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1))


pprint(sortedData)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having to go through the calendar and selecting each day, as it would day a long time. You could instead go straight to the source of the information, parse the output of fetch() to beautiful soup and retrieve all the information you'd like :)

We're figuring out how many days we have in a month, passing that list into a GET request that retrieves the day. All within a loop of 12 months. You could adjust this to many previous years if you need to.

```
import requests
import calendar

def getDays(counter):

  b = calendar.monthcalendar(2018, counter)

  length = len(b)
  lengthCounter = 0
  days = []
  for x in b:
    lists = (b[lengthCounter])
    lengthCounter += 1
    for day in lists:
      if day > 0:
        days.append(day)
    else:
      pass
  return(days)

def fetch(days, month):
  if month < 10:
    month = "0" + str(month)

  for d in days:
    if d < 10:
        mod = "0" + str(d)
        re = requests.get("https://hourlypricing.comed.com/rrtp/ServletFeed?type=pricingtabledual&date=2018" + str(month) + str(mod))
        source = re.content
        print(source)
    else:
      re = requests.get("https://hourlypricing.comed.com/rrtp/ServletFeed?type=pricingtabledual&date=2018" + str(month) + str(d))
      source = re.content
      print(source)




months = 1
while months < 12:

    dayList = getDays(months)
    print(fetch(dayList, months))
    months +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are free APIs for historic price info. It allows you to specify ranges to retrieve values for.
It is 5 minute prices but there are a variety of options for querying and different return formats

Example data range format for GET request returning json

https://hourlypricing.comed.com/api?type=5minutefeed&datestart=201712310000&dateend=201812310000

The dates provided are in the format: yyyyMMddhhmm

API info here

https://hourlypricing.comed.com/hp-api/

---

> JSON: returns an array of json objects with elements UTC millis and
>   price.

```
[
{"millisUTC":"1434686700000","price":"2.0"},
{"millisUTC":"1434686100000″,"price”:"2.5"},
{"millisUTC":"1434685800000″,"price”:"2.5"}
]
```

Comment: While it provides historical prices it does not provide a Day-Ahead Hourly Price for a given day.

Comment: Nope. But it may be of use to others looking at something similar. How useful is day ahead when looking retrospectively? I don't know this data.

Comment: For sure. Looking to answer this question actually and learn along the way.